# How is it possible to have Kriyas HaTorah 5 days in a row without Hallel?

Tags: riddle, torah-reading

How is it possible to have Kriyas HaTorah 5 days in a row without Hallel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Rosh Hashanah is on Thursday and Friday (as it was this year). Then you have:

Thursday - reading for 1st day Rosh Hashanah (Gen. 21:1-34, Num. 29:1-6)

Friday - reading for 2nd day Rosh Hashanah (Gen. 22:1-24, Num. 29:1-6)

Shabbos - Parshas Haazinu (Deut. 32:1-52)

Sunday - reading for (postponed) Tzom Gedaliah (Ex. 32:11-14,34:1-10)

Monday - first part of Parshas Vezos Haberachah (Deut. 33:1-17)